# How do i move text inside a button?

Tags: html, css

I need to move the text inside a button horizontally on click to make a win95-ish click effect.

I've tried doing it with translate, but that moves the whole button, not just its contents. How do i move the text? I'd like to avoid creating elements inside buttons or messing with the padding.

```css
body {
  background-color: #008080;
}

button {
  background-color: #C0C0C2;
  color: #000;
  padding: 5px 12px;
  border-top: 2px solid #fff;
  border-left: 2px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  border-right: 2px solid #000;
}

button:active {
  border-top: 2px solid #000;
  border-left: 2px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  border-right: 2px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Click me!</button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qz0gt378/

Comment: I thought the effect was changing from outset to inset border

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a text-shadow if you don't want to use other elements.

```css
body {
  background-color: #008080;
}

button {
  background-color: #C0C0C2;
  color: #000;
  padding: 5px 12px;
  border-top: 2px solid #fff;
  border-left: 2px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  border-right: 2px solid #000;
}

button:active {
  border-top: 2px solid #000;
  border-left: 2px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  border-right: 2px solid #fff;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 0px black;
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Click me!</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change the padding of your button.

```css
body {
  background-color: #008080;
}

button {
  outline: none;
  background-color: #C0C0C2;
  color: #000;
  padding: 5px 12px;
  border-top: 2px solid #fff;
  border-left: 2px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  border-right: 2px solid #000;
}

button:active {
  border-top: 2px solid #000;
  border-left: 2px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  border-right: 2px solid #fff;
  padding: 6px 11px 4px 13px;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Click me!</button>
```

Comment: But then i have to change it in more places in code every time i want to tweak something, so this wouldn't work.